# error with adding item to list

Tags: vb.net, project

I'm trying to make a game using vb,so i made this class:

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
    Module EntityI
    Public entities As List(Of Entity)
    Public Function getEntity(ByVal uuid As Guid) As Entity
    For i = 0 To entities.Count - 1
        If entities.Item(i).getUUID = uuid Then
            Return entities.Item(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
    End Module
    Public Class Entity
Private uuid As Guid
Private location As Location
Private shape As OvalShape

Public Sub New()
    uuid = System.Guid.NewGuid
    Dim canvas As New PowerPacks.ShapeContainer
    canvas.Parent = Game
    shape = New OvalShape With {.Parent = canvas}
    shape.SetBounds(50, 50, 50, 50)
    save()
End Sub
Public Function getUUID() As Guid
    Return uuid
End Function
Public Function getLocation() As Location
    Return location
End Function
Public Sub teleport(ByVal location As Location)
    Me.location = location
End Sub
Private Sub save()
entities.add(Me)
End Sub
End Class
```

So this gives an error at entities.add(Me) (NullRefernceException).
Is it something with the list or something else?
Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
Public entities As New List(Of Entity)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are new list. You are only declaring the variable as a list. Change `Public entities As List(Of Entity)` to `Public entities As New List(Of Entity)`

Comment: Same answer as Karen's ^